# How to update two parameters of a Blazor component atomically

Tags: razor, blazor

I'm creating a component `Foo` that takes two parameters. I want to bind two variables like this:

`<Foo SelectedPage="@SelectedPage" SelectedPageElement="@SelectedPageElement" />`

How can I make sure I update both `SelectedPage` and `SelectedPageElement` at the same time and only have `Foo` rerender after both variables are updated?

I want to be able to do something like

```
SelectedPage = nextPage;
SelectedPageElement = null
```

without rendering the component twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent unnecessary rerendering by overriding [`ComponentBase.ShouldRender()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.componentbase.shouldrender?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

An example, using simple data types for the component parameters:

- You can create a private field for each of the parameters. The private fields are populated at component initialization and are then used to keep track of the *latest updated value set* (i.e. the latest state in which *both* parameters were updated).
- Then, by overriding `ShouldRender()`, you can make sure that both of the parameters actually have an updated value before you allow rerendering to happen.

The code for **Foo** may look something like:

```csharp
[Parameter]
public int SelectedPage { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public int SelectedPageElement { get; set; }

private int _selectedPage;
private int _selectedPageElement;

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    _selectedPage = SelectedPage;
    _selectedPageElement = SelectedPageElement;
}

protected override bool ShouldRender()
{
    if (SelectedPage == _selectedPage)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (SelectedPageElement == _selectedPageElement)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Both parameters were updated --> update the tracking fields, let component rerender

    _selectedPage = SelectedPage;
    _selectedPageElement = SelectedPageElement;

    return true;
}
```

Example fiddle illustrating the result [here](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/fki693cb).

Answer (score 2):

There are various events that cause a re-render, Foo doesn't render just because you set `SelectedPage = nextPage;`.  It all depends on the context in which you are running those two lines of code.

The following code demonstrates a normal event driven example and shows the number of render events that occur.

#### Foo

```
<h3>Foo rendered @renders</h3>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string? SelectedPage { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string? SelectedPageElement { get; set; }

    // set to 1 as ShouldRender is not called on the first render event
    private int renders = 1;

    protected override bool ShouldRender()
    {
        renders++;
        return true;
    }
}
```

#### Demo page

```
@page "/"

<h1>Hello</h1>

<Foo SelectedPage="@this.selectedPage" SelectedPageElement="@this.selectedPageElement" />
<div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=this.OnClick>Update</button>
</div>

@code
{
    private string? selectedPage;
    private string? selectedPageElement;

    private void OnClick()
    {
        selectedPage = "Hello";
        selectedPageElement = "Me";
    }
}
```

As you can see there's only one render event associated with the button click.  You don't need to write extra code.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a

```
public record Selection(string SelectedPage, string SelectedPageElement)
```

and instead of two `[Parameter]` make the `[Parameter]` be an instance of the record.

Comment: The problem with this is you now have an object you are passing as a parameter.  The render sees object, decides it can't tell if it's been updated or not and calls `SetParamatersAsync` on the component whenever a UI event occurs, thus forcing a re-render.  The following will re-render the component `<button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="() => {}">Do Nothing</button>`.  In the current release it doesn't understand the difference between a record and a class, though it ought to!

Comment: Yes, you would still have to mitigate multiple renderings by overriding `ShouldRender` as shown in other answers. My idea is to turn the write-access to multiple parameters into one and making it atomic. Also I dont see why the write to any of these properties should trigger a rerender, as long as you do not call `StateHasChanged()` between writes you should be good (except if you are in serverside Blazor, then you should also avoid an `await` between writing to the properties)